# Printing the 1000th prime number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int ctr = 0;
    int count = 1; //Counts the nth prime number
    int num = 3;
    int div = 2;  //Potential factors of the number

    while(count <= 1000){
        while(div < num){  
            if(num%div == 0){ 
            ctr += 1; //If ctr is equal to 0, then num is prime
            }
            div += 1;
        }
        if(ctr == 0){ //If num is prime, count increases by 1
            count += 1;
        }
        num += 1;
    }   
    cout << num;
}
```

This is the code that I made to output the 1000th prime number. However, there must be something wrong with my program since it does not output 7919, which is the 1000th prime number.

Comment: You never reset the value of `div`. Or `ctr`.

Comment: Have you covered debuggers in class yet? Stepping through your code would make it obvious what is wrong.

Comment: I got it. @Daniel, thank you for reminding me that. Also, I changed `count = 1` to `count = 2` and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually helps to refactor code like this into functions that have a clearly defined and testable behavior. For instance, the inner part of your code is a '`isPrime`' function, and if you define it like this:

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
  int div = 2;  //Potential factors of the number
  while (div < n) {
    if (n % div == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    ++div;
  }
  return div == n;
}
```

It is easy to test, either through unit testing, or just manually checking if `isPrime()` works ok.

That makes the rest of the code more easy to write (and more importantly, read):

```
  int primeCount = 0;
  int n = 1;
  while (primeCount < 1000) {
    if (isPrime(n++)) {
      ++primeCount;
    }
  }
  --n;
  std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

---

As for why your code doesn't work. You should debug it. Go through line by line and see where it deviates from your expectations. Start out with finding the 3rd prime number, and not the 1000th.

Your `isPrime` part does not do what it is supposed to. Finding out why isn't hard, and you should definitely do that as a debugging-exercise, and not go with an easy answer from stackoverflow.

Comment: What helps qua performance is checking for devisible by 2, 3 and then plusplussing twice, because you can skip checking if divisible by even numbers

Comment: @Simon For sure. I'm guessing this is a homework exercise, and performance not the first priority. Dynamic programming would help even more.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>




int main(){

int ctr = 0;
int count = 1; //Counts the nth prime number
int num = 3;
int div = 2;  //Potential factors of the number

while(count <= 1000){
    while(div < num){  
        if(num%div == 0){ 
        ctr += 1; //If ctr is equal to 0, then num is prime
        }
        div += 1;
    }
    if(ctr == 0){ //If num is prime, count increases by 1
        count += 1;
    }
    num += 1;
    ctr=0;
    div=2;
}   
printf("%d",num);
}
```